# ImportError: uncompyle2 even though it's installed

Tags: python, decompiler

I am trying to use the code in this github project: https://github.com/Katharsis/unfrozen_binary

When I try to run the script: python unfrozen_binary_cx_Freeze.py

I receive the following error:

```
File "/path/to/file/unfrozen_binary-master/common.py", line 20, in <module>
    from decompilers.uncompyle2 import uncompyle_file
ImportError: No module named decompilers.uncompyle2
```

I checked common.py and it imports uncompyle package as shown below:

```
if python_version[0] == 3:
    from decompilers.unpyc3.unpyc3 import dec_module
elif python_version[0] in (1, 2):
    from decompilers.uncompyle2 import uncompyle_file
    from decompilers.uncompyle2 import Walker
```

There is no decompilers package available.

However, I already have uncompyle2 installed so, I edited the above code to use uncompyle2 only since I am using Python version 2.7

Now, I receive the ImportError for uncompyle2 even though I have both uncompyle2 and uncompyle6 installed. Even confirmed this with pip show command.

```
>>> import uncompyle2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named uncompyle2
>>> import uncompyle6
>>>
```

However, pip show command shows that uncompyle2 is installed:

```
$ pip show uncompyle2
Name: uncompyle2
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: Python byte-code to source-code converter
Home-page: https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6
Author: Hartmut Goebel
Author-email: h.goebel@crazy-compilers.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: uncompyle6
```

Is anyone able to get the above github project working?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind it says `decompilers.uncompyle2`, not just `uncompyle2`. Have you tried `pip install decompilers`?

Comment: There's no such package called as decompilers. At least, I could not find one. Could you find it?  There was even an issue logged in github for this by someone: https://github.com/Katharsis/unfrozen_binary/issues/1 however there's no response.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is my doing: with pip install of uncompyle2, right now you are getting uncompyle6, not uncompyle2.

This decision was made because at the time this was done, there wasn't anyone who would step up to maintain any (of the many) forks of uncompyle2. The packager of uncompyle2 on pypi wasn't one of the authors, just a packager. So it was really an untenable situation for him.

If someone wants to step up and maintain uncompyle2, they can contact me and I'll transfer uncompyle2 to someone else. The best maintained version of uncompyle2 seems to be [the one under the wibiti account](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2).

If you install that from *github* sources, then change `from decompilers.uncompyle2 import` to `from uncompyle2 import` in the unfreeze_binary code.

I see you have opened an issue [with the project in question.](https://github.com/Katharsis/unfrozen_binary/issues/1). That is good! However since that it seems like the *only* issue that has ever been opened, and this issue was opened a while ago, this suggests that project is dead like many of the `uncompyle2` forks and `unpyc3` which only handles Python 3.3. (Many python packages packages, like pip, have recently been telling me that they no longer support Python 3.3, so I doubt unpyc3 is of much use nowadays)

The last commit to the `unfrozen_binary` project is over 4 years ago. So given its low github ratings, the lack of commits and supports, I would expect other problems down the line.

That said, all of this is open source so I guess you or someone else could fork the code and get it working again. If you do that though, I'd suggest using uncompyle6 which supports lots of Python versions including 2.7, 3.3 and current 3.x versions. For that instead of `from decompilers.uncompyle2 import` you'd use `from uncompyle6 import`.